# UITableView Row Persistance - why does "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" crash

Tags: xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` that stores the selected row in User Defaults. The `tableView` is part of a menu structure that may be reloaded during the lifetime of the application, hence I want the persistence between loads. In `viewDidLoad`, this `UserDefault` is checked for existence, and I call

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle)];
```

This works fine, as expected. However, it doesn't actually select the row, it just highlight's it. If I subsequently call

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

I get a crash - "unrecognised selector sent to instance". Why?

Comment: The row's state should be set in your model. So if the menu item is selected then the data model of your menu should have an item in it that is selected. To show it as selected you will just need to reload the table. If you want to select it programmatically you just set the model value as selected, perform the same method that you would if the user selected it manually, and reload the table so that the menu item appears selected to the user.

Answer (score 0):

`[self tableView:self.tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:path]` will call **YOUR** implementation of the deselection method (which is defined in UITableViewDelegate).

You get a crash since you didn't implement it in your delegate.

You should call:
`[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO];`

Comment: Hi Gilad, thanks for the reply. I made an error in the original post, namely I put didDeselect, instead of didSelect. My mistake, sorry. However, changing the method still leaves my issue. If I try your method, changing the name accordingly: [self.tableView SelectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO]; - I have this working as per the original post. That is, I can select the row, but not trigger the action that selecting the row fires in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. If I try [self.tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath...] I get a compiler error - "UITableView does not declare a selector called..."

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is a protocol method implemented by your class and not UITableView that is why it is complaining.

Comment: As a quick guideline - all methods start with "did" or "will" (didDeselect, willSelect, etc.) are callbacks method implemented by YOU. They are being called by the relevant control (UITableView in your case) and should never be called directly by the programmer. Usually a control implement a call (deselectRowAtIndexPath for example) which you can use.
Very often, callbacks are only being called based on user interaction via the GUI. If you select/deselect a cell programmatically - you should call your own callback as well (if implemented).

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView works via two delegate protocols, [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The class that defines your UITableView should implement these protocols and you should set the delegate and datasource of the UITableView to "self". You should not call the protocol methods directly which is most likely the reason for your crash.

In order to select a particular row based on your data model (User Default), you will need to set the [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) selected property to "YES" in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: for the row that is being rendered.

I recommend going through this tutorial to help you understand UITableView's better.

http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/